# Append to an arary field in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using `Firebase` and `Vuejs` to create an database element, which has object array inside.

[image]

That's how the field looks, and I want to add tasks through the form into the 'moreTasks' as an array.

I tried using this, but it just creates new entity in the database.

```js
db.collection('Tasks').add({
    tasker: this.tasker.taskerName
})
```

I also tried checking API but I couldnt understand the refs, because I was using different methods to achieve that goal.

```
creatTask() {
  db.collection('Tasks').add({
    task_id: this.task_id,
    name: this.name,
```

What would be correct way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can append an item to an array using [FieldValue.arrayUnion()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue.html#arrayunion) as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).  For example:

```
// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
    regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I still can't figure out how to read specific collection ID, but Ill have a look on API

Comment: Works well.  For removal you can use: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer used to be correct but is now **wrong**. Now there **is** an atomic append operation using the *arrayUnion* method:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

This is true as long as you are using firestore and not real time db (which I assume is the case from the tags)