# Cloud Firestore: Add/remove items in ArrayValue field via REST API's PATCH method?

Tags: rest, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for a way to add/remove data from an ArrayValue field, via the Firestore REST API.

I'm able to send the [following PATCH request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/patch), to set all values of an array fields in a document, via the following:

**Request Url**

```
/v1beta1/projects/MY_APP/databases/(default)/documents/MY_COLLECTION/MY_DOCUMENT_ID?updateMask.fieldPaths=document_array&key=MY_KEY
```

**Request Body**

```
{
    "fields" : {
        "document_array" : { 
            "arrayValue" : { 
                "values" : [
                    { "stringValue" : "item_value_0" }, 
                    { "stringValue" : "item_value_1" }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, the document with id MY_DOCUMENT_ID in collection MY_COLLECTION updates so that the `document_array` field is populated with strings:

`['item_value_0', 'item_value_1']`.

Using the REST APIs PATCH method, I would like to add/remove/update/manipulate ArrayValue fields in my document `MY_DOCUMENT_ID` (ie [as outlined in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231957/firestore-add-value-to-array-field)).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible today.  You could [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) stating what you want (it's been asked before).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check `appendMissingElements` in `FieldTransform`. That's the endpoint to use arrayUnion.

[Firestore REST Write DocumentTransform](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/Write#FieldTransform)